# Is JMS is platform dependent? (e.g Java<->.Net)

Tags: queue, jms

I want to be able to produce messages to a client using a queue.
Producing the message and putting it on the queue should be both asynchronous  and reliable so that if a message isn't flagged as consumed it will be not be cleared from the queue.

I thought using JMS and read about its capabilities.

Is it platform dependent so that i as a Java web application can act as a producer while other 3'rd party as a .NET application can act as a consumer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends which JMS implementation you use. Here's some (not a comprehensive list, just a sampling...)

[WebSphereMQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500): Has clients for a ton of different languages.

[ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/): Clients for Java, C, C++, C#, Ruby, Perl, Python, PHP

[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html): Java, Ruby, Python, .NET, PHP, Perl, [lots more]

[Apache QPID](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/): Java, Python, C++, Perl, Python, Ruby, .NET, Go

Some JMS implementations support various client types via non-java-specific messaging protocols such as [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/), [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/) and [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/).